# Java - where to put 3rd party JARs and set classpath on Linux

Tags: java, jar

Basically two questions:

1)  Where should my third party JARs go?  Currently I'm immorally putting them in my application's package, which is immoral e.g. because the third party libs are lower level and should be able to be depended on by all my applications.

2)  Where should classpath be set?  Tutorials I've seen make it sound like it should be a global variable, but I don't know this because it needs to be project-dependent, i.e. project X needs libraries L and M but project Y needs libraries M and N.  Currently I'm just creating a "cp" file for each application but I was wondering if there is a more canonical style.Z

Comment: You better ask 2 questions in 2 threads, because you should accept the best correct answer. Now if you mark a correct answer for q1 as accepted, you might get no more answers. From looking at the question, nobody will know why you accepted an answer - q1 or q2 answered or maybe both?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Jars you put into

```
JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/ext
```

don't need to be specified in the classpath. So this is useful for libraries you use often like apache-commons for eample.

Rarely used libraries are better called with the classpath.

Setting the classpath depends on your usage, and whether you work on a single user machine, whether it is a client or a server. Many Java apps are made for servers, where you happen to have only one classpath at all.

Comment: On my CentOS 7.0 it was `/usr/lib/jvm/jre/lib/ext/`

Comment: While this works - its a **very** bad idea.  See [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2068961/is-putting-external-jars-in-the-java-home-lib-ext-directory-a-bad-thing) for discussion.

Answer (score 2):

1> In our project, we have made a 'third-party' project which contains only the third-party jars. The main application is in a separate project which just references to third party project.

So answer to first question may be, create a separate project called 'third-party' and put all your jars there.

2>
Generally, in Linux, you make shell variables and point them to your jars/class files like below:-

```
# export GWT_HOME=/opt/smartgwt.jar
```

Then when you invoke Java, can do something like this:-

```
# java -cp $GWT_HOME <your_main_class>
```