# Making User-Made Java Classes Available To All Eclipse Projects

Tags: eclipse, class, java

This is getting to me a bit.

What should be a straightforward and well worn procedure to do something all users need to do is anything but straightforward.

I made the Java class I want to add to all new Java projects into a JAR file.
And I got it into the JRE folder using Window > Prefs > Java > Installed JREs, etc.
But come runtime, the Java interpreter just doesn't see this class as attached to my projects.

Anyone know how this pesky one is fixed ?

I'm using Eclipse 3.6.2 Helios and JRE 7.

Answer (score 2):

The JRE isn't really intended to be extended in this way. If you must store your shared libraries in the JRE, the `ext` folder should be used, rather than the top-level JRE folder. However, even this is usually a bad practice: [Is putting external jars in the JAVA_HOME/lib/ext directory a bad thing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2068961/is-putting-external-jars-in-the-java-home-lib-ext-directory-a-bad-thing).

To add dependencies to your Eclipse projects, use the project's build path. To add dependencies at run-time, use the Java class path.

Answer (score 0):

I would create a userlibrary and add the lib to the project setup. http://goo.gl/pEoto

Comment: Yes. Got this done but only could do 1 project at a time. Would like to have certain versatile classes on tap for all projects, ideally on opening a new project the myJavaLibrary folder would be tacked onto it.

Answer (score 0):

Consider to use Maven to manage your dependencies.

Comment: Never knew what Maven was till you suggested it. But this may be for more sophisticated web work, rather than plain old apps. Thanks for the info, Puce.

Comment: Actually, Maven is used for many different kinds of projects, not only web applications. And as soon as you want to build your project on a Continuous Integration Server such as Jenkins, Maven is your best bet IMHO if you're using Eclipse.

Comment: I'll take a raincheck on that, thanks for the suggestion. I reckon that since my apps are small enough codewise - most of the size of the app would be the database - then problems arising during upgrades or code improvement won't demand such powerful tools.