# What are the differences of putting JARs into JVM lib than the project lib?

Tags: java, jar, jvm

**Background**

I recently came across a Java project that requires me to put a `JAR` file `IngrianNAE-5.0.0.jar` into `/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/ext/` directory. (The instruction was made by a former developer who has left.)

The build tool does not pick up this `IngrianNAE-5.0.0.jar` during the project building process, and the project JAR file cannot run with a JVM that does not have this `IngrianNAE-5.0.0.jar` in its `lib/ext/` directory.

Also, even if I include this `IngrianNAE-5.0.0.jar` into my build path, e.g. claiming it in dependencies section in Maven pom.xml, the project still requires the JVM to have `IngrianNAE-5.0.0.jar` in its `lib/ext/` directory. (At this point, Maven can produce the project rich JAR file, which contains `IngrianNAE-5.0.0.jar`. However, `JVM` still needs to have `IngrianNAE-5.0.0.jar` in its `lib/ext/` directory. To me, it seems that this `IngrianNAE-5.0.0.jar` is not used by the project, but by JVM.)

By the way, as `IngrianNAE-5.0.0.jar` being an example, it is just one of many JARs to be added into `/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/ext/` directory along with few properties files, such as `IngrianNAE.properties`, etc.

**Question Elaboration**

Why do I have to have such JARs being added, not into the project, but into the JVM.

How does it works?

What documentations I can look into to get more information (or tutorials) about it?

Comment: If the JAR is a runtime dependency (one that your project only needs at runtime), such as database drivers, then you can be able to only add it to the runtime class-path/module-path. What you add to the project is typically what your project's source code needs in order to compile.

Comment: The `lib/ext` folder was deprecated in Java 8 and removed in Java 9. And it was only intended to extend or replace certain functionality in the standard library. It was not to just include any dependency (I don't know IngrianNAE so I can't comment if putting it in `lib/ext` was proper or not).

Answer (score 2):

[Documentation from Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/ext/basics/install.html)

> Installed extensions are JAR files in the lib/ext directory[...]
>   installed extensions extend the platform's core API[...]
>   the symbols defined by installed extensions will be visible in all Java processes

See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2068961/is-putting-external-jars-in-the-java-home-lib-ext-directory-a-bad-thing)

Answer (score 0):

Since the IngrianNAE jar file is extending the JVM capabilities through JCE, I believe (unfortunately) that the extension must be applied at the JVM level.