# Where to put external jars in jdk10

Tags: java

I've been putting external jars in jre/lib/ext in JDK8
However ,when i update my jdk to jdk10,i cannot find jre sub-directory in jdk directory. So I download jre10  from Oracle and it turns out that the ext directory is missing... where should I put those external jars?

Comment: You should probably use maven or gradle to handle your dependencies.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2068961/is-putting-external-jars-in-the-java-home-lib-ext-directory-a-bad-thing#2068979

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is no longer supported, from [Migrating to JDK 10 from JDK 8](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/migrate/toc.htm#JSMIG-GUID-2C896CA8-927C-4381-A737-B1D81D964B7B) :

> **Removed Extension Mechanism**
>
> In previous releases, the extension
>   mechanism made it possible for the runtime environment to find and
>   load extension classes without specifically naming them on the class
>   path. Starting in JDK 9, if you need to use the extension classes,
>   ensure that the JAR files are on the class path.
>
> The javac compiler and java launcher will exit if the java.ext.dirs
>   system property is set, or if the lib/ext directory exists. To
>   additionally check the platform-specific systemwide directory, specify
>   the -XX:+CheckEndorsedAndExtDirs command-line option. This causes the
>   same exit behavior to occur if the directory exists and isn’t empty.
>   The extension class loader is retained in JDK 9 (and later releases)
>   and is specified as the platform class loader (see
>   getPlatformClassLoader.)