# How do I import java.sql.* using JDK 10.0.2 and Eclipse?

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse, java-10

I am relatively new to Java programming and the class I am taking is introducing me to MySQL right now. I am using JDK 10.0.2 and my class has instructions for JDK 1.7 or 1.8. I have just downloaded the MySQL Connector file, extracted it, and have the "mysql-connector-java-8.0.12.jar" file sitting in a temp folder on my desktop. My instructor wants me to copy said file to "JAVA_HOME\jre\lib\ext". However I understand via [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51260167/where-to-put-external-jars-in-jdk10) that as of JDK 9 and up they have removed the extension mechanism and I am supposed to make an individual classpath for each project using this connector. At this stage I am trying to import java.sql.* into my eclipse project and am getting "The import java.sql cannot be resolved" as an error.

How do I properly set up the .jar file and its classpath using JDK 10.0.2 in my project in order to import java.sql.* and proceed?

As a side note, I don't know much about "Maven" but I am trying to do this manually without involving "Maven". Again, I am using Eclipse as the IDE.

Comment: `java.sql.*` packages require the `java.sql` module. So you need to make your module require it.

Comment: How would I go about doing that?

Comment: Do you have `module-info.java` files in your project?

Comment: In my JRE System Library for the project I do see "java.sql" and under that I see "module-info.class". Also in my src folder there is the "module-info.java" file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Spigot Let me help you in this case,

1. open your eclipse,
2. then right click on project in which you want to add jar file,
3. select build path > configure build path,
4. select libraries from right tab and click on add external Jar,
5. now browse mysql jar file from your temp folder, hit apply and refresh project.

now you can import mysql classes.

Comment: So I followed your instructions and added the .jar file from the temp folder on my desktop to the classpath under libraries. I now have a referenced library with said .jar file in it. I refreshed the project and I am still getting the error.

Comment: can you please post screenshot of this?

Comment: It actually seems like I needed a combination of both your answer and ernest_k's comment to make this work. When I added "requires java.sql;" to module-info.java and refreshed the project again I was able to proceed. I appreciate all the help!

Answer (score 5):

You have to include "requires java.sql;" into the module-info.java.