# JDBC driver in "Extensions" folder of macOS is not found

Tags: java, postgresql, macos, jdbc, classpath

## tl;dr

A JDBC driver `.jar` dropped into the `/Library/Java/Extensions` folder is not found by my simple Java 13 app on macOS unless I explicitly include it on the classpath.

## `Extensions` folder on Java for macOS

As I understand, for Java 13.0.1 from AdoptOpenJDK.net on [macOS Mojave](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/macOS_Mojave), [JAR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JAR_(file_format)) files dropped into the `/Library/Java/Extensions` folder should be automatically on the [classpath](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classpath_(Java)).

So I dropped the [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) for [Postgres](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PostgreSQL) into that folder: `/Library/Java/Extensions/postgresql-42.2.8.jar`.

When I run my `tryjdbc` app this way:

```bash
java -classpath tryjdbc.jar work.basil.example.App
```

… I get an error abound the Postgres [`DataSource`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.sql/javax/sql/DataSource.html) implementation class `PGSimpleDataSource` being not found.

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/postgresql/ds/PGSimpleDataSource

If I run the same app by explicitly including the JDBC driver in the `Extensions` folder, then the error goes away. I use a colon `:` character to add `/Library/Java/Extensions/postgresql-42.2.8.jar` to the classpath.

```bash
java -classpath tryjdbc.jar:/Library/Java/Extensions/postgresql-42.2.8.jar work.basil.example.App
```

➥ Am I misunderstanding the purpose of the `Extensions` folder in Java on macOS?

➥ Is there some special problem with JDBC drivers, perhaps some kind of class loader issue?

---

I do not think it is relevant, but here is my utterly simple app trying to connect to the database locally on the same host.

```
package work.basil.example;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.util.Objects;

public class App
{
    public static void main ( String[] args )
    {
        App app = new App();
        app.doIt();
    }

    private void doIt ( )
    {
        System.out.println( "Hello World!" );

        org.postgresql.ds.PGSimpleDataSource dataSource = new org.postgresql.ds.PGSimpleDataSource();

        dataSource.setUser( "postgres" );
        dataSource.setPassword( "mot-de-passe-db7!" );

        System.out.println( "BASIL - Attempting to connect to database: " );
        if ( Objects.nonNull( dataSource ) )
        {
            String sql = "SELECT CURRENT_DATE ;";
            try (
                    Connection conn = dataSource.getConnection() ;
                    PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement( sql ) ;
            )
            {
                try (
                        ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery() ;
                )
                {
                    if ( rs.next() )
                    {
                        LocalDate ld = rs.getObject( 1 , LocalDate.class );
                        System.out.println( "BASIL - date is " + ld );
                    }
                }
            }
            catch ( SQLException e )
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        System.out.println( "BASIL - all done." );
    }
}
```

Output:

> Hello World!
>
> BASIL - Attempting to connect to database:
>
> BASIL - date is 2019-11-09
>
> BASIL - all done.

Comment: The extensions mechanism was removed in Java 9.  See also 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51260167/.

Comment: @LukeWoodward That Question you linked refers to the `/lib/ext` feature of Java on other platforms. Same idea, basically, but the `Extensions` folder I refer to is specific to Java on the macOS platform.

Comment: @LukeWoodward I just tried installing Java 13 on a clean install of Mojave. The `Extensions` folder was *not* created by default when using an installer from AdoptOpenJDK. So I suppose (a) my `Extensions` folder was pre-existing, and (b) the retiring of the `/ib/ext` feature may also mean the equivalent in macOS was retired as well. Thanks. I am closing this Question as a duplicate of the one you linked.

Comment: This was never the correct place to install it. It should on the CLASSPATH of your application somehow.

Comment: @user207421 The entire point of the `/Library/Java/Extensions` folder on macOS was to automatically place its contents on the classpath. It absolutely *was* the correct place to install a JAR, but no longer.

Comment: `/Library/Java/Extensions` is the MacOS specific access to define `lib/ext`. And `lib/ext` which was not intended as a way to put random libraries on the classpath.