# Could not create the Java Virtual Machine, with message: "-Djava.ext.dirs=./lib is not supported. Use -classpath instead."

Tags: java

I used to have no issue running this command. I recently got a new computer and updated my java. I got the following error message:

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19041.867]
(c) 2020 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

(textual) C:\Stanford\stanford-ner-2018-10-16>java -Djava.ext.dirs=./lib -cp stanford-ner-3.9.2.jar 
 edu.stanford.nlp.ie.NERServer -port 9199 -loadClassifier 
 ./classifiers/english.muc.7class.distsim.crf.ser.gz
 -tokenizerFactory edu.stanford.nlp.process.WhitespaceTokenizer -tokenizerOptions tokenizeNLs=false
 -Djava.ext.dirs=./lib is not supported.  Use -classpath instead.
 Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
 Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.

 (textual) C:\Stanford\stanford-ner-2018-10-16>-Djava.ext.dirs=./lib is not supported.  Use - 
 classpath instead
 '-Djava.ext.dirs' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
  operable program or batch file.
```

My current java version is as follows:

```
java version "16" 2021-03-16
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 16+36-2231)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 16+36-2231, mixed mode, sharing)
```

The version on my old computer is:
"1.8.0_261"

Is it because of the Java version? How to fix this? Thank you very much!

Comment: Have you tried doing what the error message is suggesting?

Comment: This option was removed in Java 10.  Either change the command line as suggested or downgrade to Java 8.  See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51260167/where-to-put-external-jars-in-jdk10) for details.

Comment: No. Honestly, I know nothing about Java. I'm trying to run a Python package in Pycharm. The package uses the Standford NER classifier, which is in Java. I just run the command following the instructions in order to create the necessary dependency.

Comment: For Java 10, how should I modify the command line? Forgive me for my ignorance. I know nothing about Java. Thank you very much.

Comment: Replace `java -Djava.ext.dirs=./lib -cp stanford-ner-3.9.2.jar ...` with `java -cp ./lib;stanford-ner-3.9.2.jar ...`

Comment: Thank you very much!