# Jars in Tomcat/lib not recognized at runtime

Tags: java, tomcat, ivy

In preparation for updating my JDK, I would like to remove the `servlet-api`, `jsp-api` and `el-api` jars from the `JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/ext` directory and instead add them to the classpath as is [recommended](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51260167/where-to-put-external-jars-in-jdk10).

I attempt to do this by adding these dependencies with the provided scope.

However, when I deploy my web application (locally), I still get a `ClassNotFoundException`, which I think is caused by the 3 missing jars (when I include them in the old jdk location, this exception disappears).

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
> javax.servlet.jsp.tagext.BodyTagSupport

I double checked to make sure that the j2ee classpath is well defined for the project. From my understanding, the application should have access to the 3 jars from my server container (Tomcat) at runtime. Indeed, it seems that this classpath was well defined:

```
j2ee.platform.classpath
j2ee.server.home
```

are both defined in my project properties file.

Also, as far as I know I'm not including any of these jars in `WEB-INF/lib` so I don't think that's what's causing the issue either. I do define the jars as dependencies but I give them the `provided` scope, with versions for each jar as dictated by this chart: https://tomcat.apache.org/whichversion.html (for Tomcat version 8.0.43).

I'm building the application with `ant` on Netbeans.

Are there any other suggestions for why these jar files are not recognized at runtime?

Comment: I don't understand why you're dealing with them yourself.  Tomcat brings them, and you should take whatever it brings with it. Also,  tomcat 8.0 reached its end of life some time ago.  While you're working on your system, you might want to go with a current version (8.5 or 9)

Comment: "Tomcat brings them" - but they're only available to my application at runtime (Server container is available during runtime). They need to also be available to my application at compile time from what I understand. Re: updating Tomcat: Yes, I'll update Tomcat and JDK, but first I want to get this issue settled on an environment I know is working, then I'll update.

Answer (score 0):

When I had started the project, I clumsily placed some dependency jars in `JAVA-HOME/jre/lib/ext`.

Removing these jars solved the issue. They had dependencies bundled with them that included `jsp-api.jar` or `servlet-api.jar`.